# "Override" constructor and call grandparent constructor

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, constructor

I am using a class in a library that we'll call `LibraryClass<BaseClass>` where `LibraryClass<>` inherits from its template like so:

```
template<class BaseClass>
class LibraryClass
:
    public BaseClass
{
...
```

This class does exactly what I want, however there is a bug in the constructor. I am trying to create a derived class like this:

```
template<class BaseClass>
class MyClass
:
    public LibraryClass<BaseClass>
{
...
```

and then just add a new constructor. However, in the constructor MyClass() I need to call the constructor BaseClass() which is not the direct parent. As stated above, I don't want to call LibraryClass() as it has a bug.

How should I create this new class with a just a new constructor?

Comment: Let's say you could bypass the parent's constructor. What would ensure that the parent subobject is in a useable state (if it hasn't been initialized)?

Comment: You may try to create "bypassing" constructor inside `LibraryClass` - and force to call it, i.e. by specific arguments.

Comment: Surely this is the most novel approach to bug fixing I've seen in many years ;-)

Comment: if you don't want to call the constructor you can `malloc` the original class and point to it with a pointer (or a reference), but maybe you'll have to construct the object by yourself.

Comment: You *are* calling the `BaseClass::BaseClass` constructor; its going to be fired as part of the precondition of `LibraryClass<BaseClass>::LibraryClass`, which is *your* precondition. So how about *fixing the bug* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt there is standards-compliant way to bypass the parent constructor in the general case (if such a thing existed, what would ensure that the parent sub-object is left in a usable state?)

**IMO the best way to fix the bug is by changing `LibraryClass`.**

If you can't do that, you could copy `LibraryClass` and fix the bug in your copy. This has obvious and potentially very significant downsides.

Another potential alternative is to call the buggy constructor, and then fix up the object in `MyClass::MyClass` to work around the bug. This approach may or may not work for your case.